# How to tell if the java.util.Date object contains the time portion?

Tags: java

We are storing date and datetime as Date object.

But, late on, we need to be able tell whether the Date object is a date or datetime.

05/18/05 00:00:00 and 05/18:05 both have the hour / minute portion. I can't really tell them apart.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does Java not have a way to compare different date formats? This is trivially easy in .NET.

Comment: `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); Date x; //filled with some data `
`c.setTime(x); c.get(Calendar.YEAR) //or the field that you want`

Comment: @Jason "date formats" in java are for rendering/parsing. Dates are just a wrapped long of millis since 1970, which you can compare. Dates do not "have" a format - they are formatted by a DateFormat object.

Comment: Both dd-mm-yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd can be confusing.  I suggest that dd-Mon-YYYY (ex. 13-Feb-2012 - for an English audiance) is less confusing than both formats.

Comment: How can yyyy-mm-dd be confusing? Still unfamiliar for some, ok, even if it is the standard, but confusing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A java.util.Date is, in fact, a point in time, not a date so there is no way to use it as a date only. You will need to come up with a different approach.

Comment: Yes. The approach is flawed. We need to have different object for date and datetime.

Comment: I can't believe this was marked as the best answer. It is not a solution, just an opinion

Comment: Sometimes the solution is that there is no solution.

Answer (score 9):

Unless your datetimes are guaranteed to not be at midnight, ie they never have `HH:mm:ss` of `00:00:00`, there is no solid way to tell "dates" and datetimes that happen to be at midnight apart.

If your datetimes are never at midnight, then:

```
if (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(object).equals("00:00:00"))
```

would do to determine if the `Date` object is a "date".

I think your design is flawed and you should find another solution. I also think that the name of the `Date` class is flawed and causes this kind of confusion.

Comment: `"00:00:00".equals(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(object));`

Comment: just better practice to have string literals on the other side. although I don't think the format method would ever return null

Comment: also shouldn't it be "HH:mm:ss" instead of "hh:mm:ss" ?

Comment: @rpt [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) in java are only useful to avoid NPE caused by invoking a method on a null, but here it doesn't help, because the return from `.format()` can't be null. And yes, it should be `HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 3):

Using Apache commons-lang-3:

```
DateUtils.truncate(fecha, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).equals(fecha)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for parsing, formatting or 3rd parties libraries.
You can easily do:

```
Calendar c = ...
c.setTime(date);
//this doesn't care about nanos
if(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) > 0) {
....
}
```

PD: I do this with 1000-25.000 objects and doesn't seem to jeopardize the performance, but of course will all depend on where and why you want to do this

Comment: Is this approach more effective or comparing the time portion as `String` how _Bohemian_ described ?

Comment: As I said, this "approach" doesn't need a SimpleDateFormat (which is not a **cheap object** to be created if u will make a lot of times the comparison), also SDF is not Thread Safe, so depending the context (multi-thread) it may fail and a few more reasons that are off topic

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use [Google's DateTime](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/DateTime.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29) library for validation.

It has parseDateTime and parseDate methods that will throw NumberFormatException if they're not formatted correctly.

Then, you could do...

```
try {
   DateTime someVar = DateTime.parseDate("your_date_as_a_string");
} catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException nfe) {
  // This isn't a date...
}

try {
   DateTime someVar = DateTime.parseDateTime("your_date_as_a_string");
} catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException nfe) {
  // This isn't a date/time...
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using exceptions for flow control!

Comment: As a matter of fact, when working with user input (i.e. text boxes on a web form) where you need to validate if the user has supplied a date correctly, using a parser on their supplied input would be the only way I'm aware of to validate it...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're actually dealing with `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` instances as obtained from a JDBC `ResultSet` while they are declared against their superclass `java.util.Date`, right?

In that case, just use `instanceof`.

```
if (date instanceof java.sql.Date) {
    // It was originally a DATE.
} else if (date instanceof java.sql.Timestamp) {
    // It was originally a TIMESTAMP (DATETIME).
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with the solutions posted here regarding modding the raw time value to see if it has a time portion, as Dmitri said, the flaw is that if the `Date` value has a time portion of exactly midnight, there's no way to tell.

So, thinking a bit laterally here, you could presumably create your own class that extends `Date` which has a member variable boolean called "isDateTime". Then, when you initially load in your date or datetime value, set that boolean to true or false depending on whether it's a datetime or not.